# Keeping track of multiple ID's in a Quiz using Sessions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, session, cookies

Im making a quiz in MVC. After all the questions have been answered, the results is written to the database when the quiz is completed. So far so good.

There are both multichoice and singlechoice questions.
The answers and questions are taken from a database, and are going to change over time.

During the quiz i keep track of the replies from the user, by using a few sessions.
I have a int (index) to keep track of which question is the current, the prev. and the next.
I have a List<-int-> with QuestionID's.
I have a List<-List<-int->-> with answers-ids so i can see what answers fit what question.

Everything is going very smooth as long as the user use my "previous question" and "next question" buttons, but if the user uses the "back" and "forward" buttons it ruins my index.

So my question is how do i prevent this from happening?

Can i force the user back to "home", clear the sessions and start again, if he presses the back-button?

Let me know if you need more information...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In webforms I would add the "current index" to the ViewState and reset my Session index to that value, if present.

MVC doesn't have ViewState, so maybe you can use a `<input type=hidden>` for a similar effect.

Comment: Keeping track of the index is no problem.
Its when the user uses the back (and forward) button in the browser, it gets messed up.

Comment: @PaludaN - When the user uses the browser's back button, he gets the previous value of the "currentindex". So you can reset the session's idea of "current index".